# Why is form.is_valid() evaluating false on POST request

Tags: android, python, django, rest, post

I am struggling with some prototype/test/learn like android app, that is supposed to `GET` and `POST` requests to a database via json/rest and django. I installed restless for django and the `GET` request is working like a charm.

models.py

```
...
class Exercise(models.Model):
name = models.TextField()
duration = models.TextField()
repeats = models.TextField()
creationtime = models.TextField()
pausetime = models.TextField()
alarmsound = models.TextField()
description = models.TextField()
type = models.TextField()
...
```

views.py

```
....
from restless.views import Endpoint
from restless.models import serialize
from restless.http import Http201, Http400
from .models import *
from restinterface.forms import ExerciseForm

class ExercisesList(Endpoint):
    def get(self, request):
        return serialize(Exercise.objects.all())
...
```

So, for the POST request, I implemented this little form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *
class ExerciseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exercise
```

On the android side I am creating a `List<NameValuePair>` which is then transformed into a `UrlEncodedFormEntity`. Sending it over to django also seems to work, but then on the django side a HTTP 500 gets thrown.

```
class ExercisesList(Endpoint):
def get(self, request):
    return serialize(Exercise.objects.all())

def post(self, request):
    form = ExerciseForm(request.data)

    # USED TO TEST IF SAVE ACTUALLY WORKS - and it does work!!!
    exercise = form.save()

    if form.is_valid():
        print 'Form seems to be valid ' + form.data
        exercise = form.save()
        return Http201(serialize(exercise))
    else:
        print 'Form seems to be invalid ' + form.data
        print 'invalid data'
        return Http400(reason='invalid author data',
            details=form.errors)
```

sample output:

```
[06/Jun/2014 02:38:43] "GET /exercises/ HTTP/1.1" 200 220
[{'name': u'Campusboard', 'creationtime': '12', 'duration': u'no duration', 'pausetime': u'20', 'repeats':     u'5', 'type': u'repeat', u'id': 1, 'alarmsound': u'default', 'description':     u'this is a description'}]

[06/Jun/2014 02:38:49] "POST /exercises/ HTTP/1.1" 500 672
{u'name': u'Ringe', u'creationtime': u'12', u'duration': u'no     duration', u'pausetime': u'10', u'repeats': u'23', u'type': u'repeats',     u'alarmsound': u'default', u'description': u'this is a descpription'}
```

it looks like `form.is_valid()` always evaluates false. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I would also interested in getting more debugging output then the one posted above. The debug flag is already activated!

Cheers!

**EDIT**

Guess I will try to use a different approach, and keep you updated.
- switched the framework (as I am in a bit of a hurry), using django rest framework which is working perfectly for my purposes.

Comment: Did you try using `request.POST` instead of `ExerciseForm(request.data)`?

Comment: I did indeed try that, but as the framework docs use request.data I was more focused on getting this to work. Of course I could use the request.POST - I even get a querydict back, but that would render the restless framework useless wouldnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used django-restless, but it looks like `request.data` is supposed to be the result of a form submission, rather than something you pass to a Django form. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/dobarkod/django-restless/blob/master/restless/views.py#L63), that attribute is only parsed into a dict suitable for a form instantiation if you use a form-encoded header in your request.

I would recommend ignoring that attribute and using the standard `request.POST` dict.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, because I wanted to try the REST framework. Or am I understanding something completely wrong? Wouldnt using `request.POST` render the framework `restless` useless in this case?